# How do you mail perfect carcasses for side-quests?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I currently have a side-quest to mail off a perfect rabbit carcass and a perfect squirrel carcass. When I approach the post office with a rabbit carcass the option to mail it remains greyed out.

I'm mid-way through chapter 3.

Searching google brings up conflicting posts on sites like Reddit. Some claim mailing is a feature later unlocked in chap.3, and some claim they've mailed the carcasses in chap.2. Some claim they need to be unskinned, and some say they've skinned them.

Does anyone have some confirmed information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you are doing the Wildlife Art Exhibition mission.

If I had to guess, you probably only have one of the carcasses (your post makes it sound like you just have the rabbit).  When you have both in your inventory, the option to mail them should become available at the post office (the Wildlife Art Exhibition mission will notify you as well).  I also recall skinning the rabbit and being able to send it no problem (I don't think squirrels are skinned).

Some more info [here](http://www.gosunoob.com/red-dead-redemption-2/mail-perfect-rabbit-squirrel-carcass-wildlife-art-exhibition/) so you don't have to rely on just my anecdotal advice.

Answer (score 2):

When you get a perfect squirrel carcass, you put it in your side pouch so it's on you all the time. With the rabbit, you attach it to your horse. After you get both, head to the post office, then take the rabbit off your horse and carry it over to the postmaster and it will allow you to send it. You must have both before you can send it, and has absolutely nothing to do with story progression.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in Chapter two. Take both to the post office and you can send them. The post office near Emerald Ranch is a good spot to hunt both animals and send them quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue i've encountered and i know i'm a little late to the game but i do believe i've cracked

When you have both animal carcass in perfect condition (your horse near buy the post office you dont have to remove it) the option to send will appear as a letter with a little bird on it rather than trying to send both carcass

Hope that helps future late comers to the game

Answer (score -1):

You probably have your bandana equiped, same happened to me. Unequip your bandana and you can send mail.